# How do I make a transform Rotate n times per second?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want it to spin at speed from 0 to very fast. 
But if I'm changing the value of the spin to 10 it's almost not moving and 200 make it move slowly. 2000 make it move fast, but how fast is that?  If I want to make it spin 10 times per second how do I use `Rotate` to do that?

```
public float rotationSpeed;

private void Update()
{
  scaling.objectToScale.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: So you can fine tune the speed I assume.

Comment: because that's the behavior of the function

Comment: I edited the question to be more appropriate for Stack Overflow. Before, it was way too vague to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The way you are using it, `rotationSpeed` is a measure of degrees turned per second

`Rotate`'s second parameter takes in a number of degrees to rotate.

`Time.deltaTime` is how many seconds have passed since the last frame.

10 degrees per second means it rotates once every 36 seconds (360/10 = 36).

2000 degrees per second means it rotates once every 0.18 seconds (360/2000 = 0.18) or in other words, it rotates 5.56  times per second  (2000/360 = 5.56).

If you want to rotate `n` times per second, do:

```
rotationSpeed = n * 360f;

// ...

scaling.objectToScale.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

If you want to take `n` seconds to rotate once, do:

```
rotationSpeed = 360f / (float)n;

// ...

scaling.objectToScale.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```