# Unity c# transform Function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am new to unity I am learning to make a driving game and i am following a course from udemy, so far thigns seems to be nice but what they didnt explain is why unity takes Floating points for its transform functions such as transform.Rotate() transform.Translate(). and also how do we calculate our value for smooth motion and what data type it pretend if we do not use f with number for example (transform.Rotate(0,0,45))<- this function make the sprite rotate in z axis super fast while z=0.1f makes it smooth in in real life 0.1f is equal to what value for us humans to understand? and how it unity reads and understands it?

Tried Values as Floating and without but couldnt understand difference also want to udnerstand how unity reads it and interpret Floating values

whats the difference between:

```
float steerSpeed = 0.1f;
update() {
// difference between below
float steerAmount = Input.GetAxis(Horizontal) * steerSpeed;
// and this
float steerAmount = Input.GetAxis(Horizontal)

transform.Rotate(0, 0, steerAmount);
}
```

Comment: The value is an angle ..  if you rotate about 45° each frame .. assuming a normal 60 frames per second .. that means 2700° per second .. well yeah that is damn fast ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# (and some of the other programming languages), the f suffix means float.

For example, `float x = 0.1f` means the value of `x` is `0.1`.

So, if you set the value of `z` in `transform.Rotate` to `0.1f`, it rotates slower than `z = 45`.

Comment: so it will rotate 0.1 degree per second? and not 1 degree per second, so it will read just as we humans read it generally, thank you now I understand it, and now i will be able to apply values as well

Comment: @Programmer, if you call transform.Rotate in an `Update` function then it will rotate by that much every time Update is called, which is _roughly_ (but not necessarily) once per frame.  You should multiply your rate of rotation (in degrees per second) by Time.deltaTime (the amount of time elapsed this update), to get the number of degrees to rotate in this update.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263196/how-do-i-make-a-transform-rotate-n-times-per-second

Comment: What you would rather want to do is using `45 * Time.deltaTime` which converts your previous `45° per frame` into a frame rate independent smooth `45° per second` ..

Comment: @Wyck what do you mea by roughly?! `Update` **is** called once a frame .. exactly.

Comment: @derHugo Of course, [you're right](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), but I said "roughly" because it depends how you define a _frame_.  Certainly not a frame of video as perceived by your monitor.  Also not a frame as defined by the physics engine (that would be fixedUpdate). In this case Update is called once per frame as perceived by the _renderer_. The question was about "smooth in real life", so I thought it apropos to hedge about what a _frame_ is.  "smooth in real life" frames would be frames of video on the display device. I probably said it poorly.

Comment: @Wyck `frames would be frames of video on the display device` well .. or in other words rendered frames .. I define frame as anyone would on this context yes .. a rendered frame is a frame that is output on your device that is executing the code

Comment: Thanks guys, this explains also @Programmer you explained Time.deltaTime as well how its used as it was my next question for following new Input System in Unity